# Handle two slideUp/Down via classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've two menus in mobile view of my website. If you click on the hamburger bar, they should slide down/up. This is basically  no problem for me.

My HTML looks like this:

```
...
<div class="foo">
  <div class="trigger menu1">
    ..
  </div>
  <div class="trigger menu2">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
...
<nav id="main-navi">
  ...
</nav>
<ul id="info-navi>
  ...    
</ul>
...
```

At the moment I solved it via jQuery with click-events for every single trigger. Like this...

```
...
$(".trigger.menu1").click(function() {
  ...
  $("#main-navi").slideDown();
});
$(".trigger.menu2").click(function() {
  ...
  $("#info-navi").slideDown();
  ...
});
...
```

This works fine, but I want to use it more easier and without so much code. Isn't it possible to get just an event for the .trigger and refer it just to the class to trigger the menu to slide down?

I tried it with something like, but it doesn't work:

```
if ($this.hasClass("menu1")) {
  $("#main-navi").slideDown();
} else {
  $("#info-navi").slideDown();
}
```

Is there a way to get this working?

Regards,
Markus

Comment: Hi, can you put it in a fiddle or snippet, so I can see what actually happens...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have solved your problem. Though there are other possible solutions to this, but this code works quite well for your purpose:

```
$(".trigger").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($this.hasClass("menu1")) {
    $("#main-navi").slideDown();
  } else {
    $("#info-navi").slideDown();
  }
});//.trigger click
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HTML5` `data-*` attribute to achieve this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-target')).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <div data-target="main-navi" class="trigger">
    Menu Opener 1
  </div>
  <div data-target="info-navi" class="trigger">
    Menu Opener 2
  </div>
</div>
...
<nav id="main-navi">
  Menu Slide 1
</nav>
<ul id="info-navi">
  Menu Slide 2
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are heading in the right direction, but you had a small syntax error in your code. Try this:

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function(){
    var isMenu1 = $(this).hasClass('menu1');
    if(isMenu1){
        $("#main-navi").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#info-navi").slideDown();
    }
});
```

`$this` is incorrect, should have been `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,

```
var clickedItem = $(".foo").find('div');

clickedItem.click(function(e){
    e.prventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('menu1')){
        $("#main-navi").slideDown();
    }else{
        $("#info-navi").slideDown();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use slideToggle() jquery function ?
You can find help here http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ .

Comment: Can't use it, because when first slides down, the second has to slide up.